# Dimensionality reduction with SVD specifying energy to keep

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I'd like to reduce the dimensionality of a few datasets with [SVD](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD.html). However, the current sklearn interface only allows me to specify the number of components to reduce to (through the `n_components` parameter).

This feels "hard-coded", as some datasets have much larger dimensions than others, and there is no correct number of components to determine *a priori*. Specifying the amount of energy to keep from the original matrix (or more specifically, dataset, in this case) is a better option (the fastest "reference" I could grab is in [this book](http://www.mmds.org/), in [chapter 11](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds/ch11.pdf) (to be more specific, page 20 of this PDF, in the "How Many Singular Values Should We Retain?" box).

**Is there any way I can do that in scikit-learn, using SVD?**

I have tried modifying the source code to allow this, however the current code does an "optimization step" which depends on the number of components passed to the code. If I don't pass the number of components (i.e. leave it at the default number), only 12 components will be decomposed (and the energy calculation will use only these 12 components). In order to do the calculations based on the energy, I have to set `n_components` to the total number of features of each dataset (going to the safe side), which is **extremely** slow for some larger datasets.

Any ideas for solving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see [from the documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.PCA), you can use explained variance ratio (which is I think what you are looking for) or using an "mle" estimate.

The `PCA` class will always compute the full SVD, though, so you wont get a speedup. You can use `RandomizedPCA`, but that does not allow selecting the number of components based on explained variance ratio. You should try it anyhow, because it will probably be a lot faster than `PCA` for large datasets, even if you compute all components (assuming `n_features` is not huge).

Comment: From the `PCA` documentation, what is the difference between using `PCA` or `TruncatedSVD`? I got to `TruncatedSVD` because of how it seems to be better suited for text analysis, but it appears that both methods will end up at approximately the same answer.
Using `RandomizedPCA` seems to be the same thing I already implemented with a "hack" into `TruncatedSVD`, which is what I'd like to optimize. My dataset is large both in number of samples and number of features.

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't see you where using truncated SVD already. What is ``n_samples`` and ``n_features`` for which that is slow?

Comment: It starts to get slow when `n_samples` is almost 10k, and `n_features` is around 50k (at the beginning of the dimensionality reduction. Of course it will be lower at the end). It takes around 13 minutes to run on a 2.5GHz machine (running only on one core). I'd like to reduce that time even further, given that some datasets are much bigger.

Comment: Is that dense data? When both ``n_samples`` and ``n_features`` are large, the problem is just pretty slow. What I would do is use the largest ``n_components`` that you find is acceptable in runtime and see what the reconstruction error and the eigenvalues look like.

Comment: No. It's from a lot of text, so it's a sparse matrix (and exactly why I need to use TruncatedSVD - because it works with sparse matrices). This is my current approach - to use the largest `n_components` the memory can handle and just accept it.
I believe the question is answered, right now it appears we're just talking about ideas, but it appears the problem just doesn't have a clear solution. If that's the case, I'll accept the answer.